# smartctl over USB - on external hdd maxtor m3

Tags: hard-disk, usb-drive, smartctl

any hint to use smartctl on *Maxtor M3 2,5" 4TB* external HDD?

It is listed as supported here:
https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices

I tried these options:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-33-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sdb: Unknown USB bridge [0x0bc2:0x61b7 (0x000)]
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary


sudo smartctl -d sat -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-33-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.



sudo smartctl -d sat -T permissive -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-33-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Mon Aug 27 20:44:01 2018 CEST
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

But nothing seems to work, I am on xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It's possible that the USB bridge, even with same vendor/device id, has changed and now doesn't support SAT. If you need the SMART info urgently, open the enclosure and connect up the harddisk directly to SATA; that will remove the USB-to-SATA bridge which causes the trouble.

Comment: The device is completely new, I bought it because it is on the list and I want to keep an eye on the smart values. Good idea, but with my notebook, I can't connect it directly.  If I can't check the health with smartmontools now or in future versions,  then it is maybe wrong HDD for my case.

Comment: This is almost certainly the USB bridge that isn't supported by linux for these commands, or that the USB bridge is not capable altogether.

Comment: Did you find out? I have the same pb. I can get info using "sudo smartctl -i -d scsi /dev/sda" but can't activate smart even though it's available (same drive as you) :/